# The counter on the status bar starts without connecting

Tags: android, chronometer

I have a calling app. When I put the application in the background after starting the call, the call stopwatch starts in the status bar. When the call is connected, the stopwatch resets and starts again.

In other applications, the stopwatch does not start until the call is connected.

Does this place have a special name?

```
style = NotificationCompat.CallStyle.forOngoingCall(person,intent);

new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyApplication.getContext(), getNotificationChannel(type))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setStyle(style);
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]